# C# Visual Studio 2008, include DLL to exe?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2008, data-visualization, add-on

I worked on a Little Project the last days annnd now I want to release it.

The "Problem" however is that I need the   "**System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll**" and "**System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Design.dll**" in the Folder where the .exe is located.

I figured I need these two, because I am using **VS2008** and I added the **ADDON DataVisualization** (for Charting purpose only).

Is there any way to include These 2 DLLs in the exe when compiling so that I can handle out the .exe only?

Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: While you *could* use [ilmerge](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge) potentially, it would be a better idea just to distribute both the executable and the DLL. That's how .NET is designed to work. I wouldn't expect the design-time DLL to be required though.

Comment: yeah, me neitehr i tried to delete it but then it causes "Errors" but i guess i have to except it, not a big deal =) THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit reference properties for these assemblies and set "Copy local" attribute to true. Though, I am not sure if they are redistributable in that manner.

A better manner would be to express that dependency in some sort of setup or installer program which installs it before your program runs. Or at least mention this dependency in release notes so your users can be pointed to downloading and installing them.

Comment: I guess i have to except it, not a big deal, just wanted to ask maybe there was an easy and good way =) Thank you

Comment: Forcibly copying assemblies has the potential to violate licenses. Be very careful with directly shipping them with your application. If there's a setup program for a component, it **should** be used instead of shipping the assembly directly. **Caveat emptor**